# (Spring batch) Pollable channel with replies contains ChunkResponses even if JOB is succefully completed

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have following chunk writer configuration with getting the replies from spring batch remote chunking:

```
    <bean id="chunkWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="messagingOperations" ref="messagingGateway" />
    <property name="replyChannel" ref="masterChunkReplies" />
    <property name="throttleLimit" value="5" />
    <property name="maxWaitTimeouts" value="30000" />
</bean>

 <bean id="messagingGateway" class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate">
    <property name="defaultChannel" ref="masterChunkRequests" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="2000" />
</bean>

<!-- Remote Chunking Replies From Slave -->
<jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="masterJMSReplies"
                             destination="remoteChunkingRepliesQueue"
                             connection-factory="remoteChunkingConnectionFactory"
                             channel="masterChunkReplies">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10" />
</jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="masterChunkReplies">
    <int:queue />
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="loggingChannel"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

My remotely chunked step is running perfectly, all data are processed with very good performance, all steps ends in COMPLETED state. But problem is that masterChunkReplies queue channel contains ChunkResponses after end of the job. Documentation doesn't say anything about it, is that normal state?

Problem is that I can't run a new job then, because it then crashes at:

```
Message contained wrong job instance id ["
                + jobInstanceId + "] should have been [" + localState.getJobId() + "]."
```

There is a simple workaround, cleaning the masterChunkReplies queue channel at the start of the job, but I'm not sure if it is correct...

Can you please clarify this?

Comment: It's not normal; they all should be consumed. See `afterStep` in the `ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter`. DEBUG logging is your friend to watch the reply consumption.

Comment: afterStep ends with Waited for 6 results...ExitStatus.COMPLETED.addExitDescription("Waited for " + expecting + " results.")....Thank you Gary for reply, I will give it more time today and we will see.

Comment: I'm curious about your answer, because having slaves consuming ChunkRequests not in parallel decreases performance.

Comment: These are the replies, not the requests. You control concurrency with a message-driven adapter with `concurrent-consumers`.

Answer (score 1):

Gary, I found the root cause.

At slaves, if I change following chunk consumer JMS adapter:

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="slaveRequests"
                                    connection-factory="remoteChunkingConnectionFactory"
                                    destination="remoteChunkingRequestsQueue"
                                    channel="chunkRequests"
                                    concurrent-consumers="10"
                                    max-concurrent-consumers="50"
                                    acknowledge="transacted"
                                    receive-timeout="5000"
                                    idle-task-execution-limit="10"
                                    idle-consumer-limit="5"

        />
```

for

```
<jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="jmsRequests" connection-factory="remoteChunkingConnectionFactory"
                             destination="remoteChunkingRequestsQueue"
                             channel="chunkRequests"
                             acknowledge="transacted"
                             receive-timeout="5000"
        >
    <int:poller fixed-delay="100"/>
</jms:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

then it works, **masterChunkReplies** queue is consumed completely at the end of job. Anyway, any attempts of consuming chunkRequests at slaves in parallalel doesn't work. MasterChunkReplies queue then contains not consumed ChunkResponses. So starting new jobs ends in

```
Message contained wrong job instance id ["
            + jobInstanceId + "] should have been [" + localState.getJobId() + "]."
```

Gary, does it mean that slaves cannot consume ChunkRequests in parallel?

Comment: Changing from a message-driven adapter to a polled adapter should make no difference. You control concurrency with a message-driven adapter with a `concurrent-consumers` property.

Comment: Gary, I temporarly made that workaround. I attached StepExecutionListener into remotely chunked step to clear masterChunkReplies replies pollable channel before starting the step. It's strange, even if there are remaining ChunkResponses in masterChunkReplies, all steps ends in COMPLETED state. ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.afterStep ends in COMPLETED as well. Could you please point me to place to debug? I tried to look into ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter but didn't find nothing suspicious. Code in there make sense more or less.

Comment: Strange - the only thing I can think of is you are somehow getting duplicate result messages - `waitForResults()` is just looking for a count and would mark the step complete; that would also explain "extra" messages in the channel. Logging at `DEBUG` for `org.springframework.integration` should show the message activity on that channel.

Answer (score 1):

Gary, after few days of struggling, I made it finally to work, ...Even with parallel ChunkRequests consuming at slaves and with empty masterChunkReplies pollable channel at the end of the job...Changes:

At master, I changed the polled inbound channel adapter consuming ChunkResponses just taken from github examples, for message driven adapter with the same level of multithreading as slaves are consuming ChunkRequests. Because I had a feeling that master is consuming ChunkResponses slowely, that's why there were additional ChunkResponses at the end of the job.

Also I misconfigured remotely chunked step....My fault.

I didn't test it yet at more then one nodes, but now I think it works as it should be.

Thank you very much for help.

regards

Tomas